# Makefile rules: how should I specify a dependency with a modified target name?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to write a rule for the following pattern:

```
SAMPLE1.tsv : SAMPLE1_result23_R1.txt  SAMPLE1_result23_R2.txt
       (do something)

SAMPLE2.tsv : SAMPLE2_result54_R1.txt  SAMPLE2_result54_R2.txt
       (do something)
(...)
```

I tried something like:

```
%.tsv: $(wildcard %_*_R1.txt) $(wildcard %_*_R2.txt)
       (do something)
```

but that does not work. How should I write this kind of rule ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to `%` inside Makefile functions.  You have to declare the dependencies separately, or use recursive Make, or generate the Makefile, or make do with less precise dependency declarations.

A simple refactoring of the dependencies is probably the easiest:

```
SAMPLE1.tsv: $(wildcard SAMPLE1_*_R1.txt) $(wildcard SAMPLE1_*_R2.txt)
SAMPLE2.tsv: $(wildcard SAMPLE2_*_R1.txt) $(wildcard SAMPLE2_*_R2.txt)
%.tsv:
        (do something with $^)
```

... where `$^` will expand to the full list of dependencies.

I suppose you could refactor even further to do a `foreach` loop over `SAMPLE1` and `SAMPLE2` but if the dependencies are this simple (and fairly stable, so you don't have to edit the repetitive parts all the time), it's not worth the hassle.